# How to extend string prototype when importing modules?

Tags: module, typescript

I am introducing modules into an existing typescript project so that it can use external modules. The current code extends basic types like string which work fine without modules. As soon as I introduce an import the compile fails.

Inside module fails:

```
 /// <reference path='../defs/react.d.ts' />

 import React = require("react");

 module ExampleModule {
     interface String {
         StartsWith: (str : string) => boolean;
     }

     if (typeof String.prototype.StartsWith !== 'function') {
          String.prototype.StartsWith = function(str) {
               return this.slice(0, str.length) === str;
          };
     }

     export function foo() { return "sdf".StartsWith("s"); }
 }
```

Outside module fails:

```
 /// <reference path='../defs/react.d.ts' />

 import React = require("react");

 interface String {
     StartsWith: (str : string) => boolean;
 }

 if (typeof String.prototype.StartsWith !== 'function') {
      String.prototype.StartsWith = function(str) {
           return this.slice(0, str.length) === str;
      };
 }

 module ExampleModule {
    export function foo() { return "sdf".StartsWith("s"); }
 }
```

But if you remove the import then it works fine:

```
 interface String {
     StartsWith: (str : string) => boolean;
 }

 if (typeof String.prototype.StartsWith !== 'function') {
      String.prototype.StartsWith = function(str) {
           return this.slice(0, str.length) === str;
      };
 }

 module ExampleModule {
    export function foo() { return "sdf".StartsWith("s"); }
 }
```

The error occurs on this line:

```
if (typeof String.prototype.StartsWith !== 'function') {
```

and reads:

```
The property 'StartsWith' does not exist on value of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you intended to extend the `String` interface, but you have to declare your interface in the same common root in order to do this (i.e. `String` is global, but your `String` interface belongs to the module file you declared it in (as soon as you use `import`, your file is treated as an external module).

This is why it works if you avoid the `import` statement - because the file is then not counted as a module - so declaring your `String` interface outside of any module means it is in the gloabl scope just like the original `String` interface.

Comment: Thanks. I find the way typescript handles modules horribly confusing (internal, external, with imports, without imports, commonjs, amd etc.). In no other language I know does an import like statement change how a unit is compiled.

Comment: It can be confusing - there is a proposal to change internal modules to "namespaces" to help with this so watch this space.